# Sorting: Put space before hyphen

Tags: r, string, sorting, character

I would like to sort a character vector , but have spaces be before hyphens in the sort.

For example

```
c("Want-#3","Want #2","I want to be first") %>% sort()
[1] "I want to be first" "Want-#3"            "Want #2"
```

I would want it to have returned

```
    [1] "I want to be first" "Want #2"            "Want-#3"
```

Obviously, I could have uses the "decreasing" option in sort, but this will not hold once my list includes other non trivial things if I wanted it to be sorted ascending.

Comment: That's strange. It sorts the way you want it on my machine. Sorting depends on `locale`: can you run `sessionInfo()` and show the results? If you're using UTF8, then space should come before `-`

Answer (score 2):

As divibisan mentions sorting depends on `locale` you can check your locale by running `Sys.getlocale()`

Running the code below will turn off locale specific sorting and produces the desired result. I'm not entirely sure about other R processes it might effect so I would be careful using it.

```
string1<-c("Want-#3","Want #2","I want to be first")
string1 %>% sort()

old <- Sys.getlocale("LC_COLLATE") #Saving my original locale to an object named "old"

Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C") # Turns off locale specific sorting 
string1 %>% sort() # Sorting should now produce desired results
```

Then to return R to the original locale just run

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", old) 
string1 %>% sort()
```

Comment: I did this, and it DID work. However, I found this as part of the tidyverse https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_order.html. This also works WITHOUT having to set a locale. Is the underlying base R locale different than what is being used here

Comment: It think it depends on the OS, but if `string1 %>% sort()` produces different results then 
`str_sort(string1)` it must be using a different locale. Kinda strange as `str_sort()` defaults to `locale= "en"` and my default locale returned by `Sys.getlocale` is "English_United States.1252." But I guess these are not equivalent.